# "Сжать" картинку с целью уменьшения размера файла

Tags: android, изображения, bitmap, resize

Используя inSampleSize  я не смог достичь уменьшения размера файла....
Например в whatsapp при отправки картинки сжимает его. Если размер файла был 3.5мб он становится размером около 100-150кб...
Как сделать чтобы размер файла картинки уменьшалась до таких размеров? при этом максимально сохранить качество (насколько это возможно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле вы в верном направлении движетесь, inSampleSize как раз и сделан для таких целей, но будьте внимательны, цифру необходимо выбирать кратной 2.
Данный код вернёт вам значение inSampleSize для заданных вами параметров ширины и высоты

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Подробнее можете почитать [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) и [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)